# WSO2 Identity server super tenant role

Tags: wso2, identity

I am very interested in using the WSO Identity server platform module as part of a tenant based SaaS platform.

Looking at the docs the WSO identity server module seems to have two logical tiers of users:  a 'super tenant' user tier for sys admin stuff, and 'tenant' level users.

For our platform design we have the concept of 'tenant groups'.  Where a 'tenant group' is a logical grouping of tenants. For, example 'tenant group' 'ACME' would be a logical grouping of tenants 'ACME UK', 'ACME USA', and 'ACME Japan'.

For this model we want a third 'tenant group' tier of users -a hybrid of the 'super tenant' user where a 'tenant group' user would have sys admin rights over just the tenants in their group.

Is it possible to adapt the WSO IS functionality to deliver this?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Currently WSO2 provides multi tenancy feature. Super Tenant has the management permission of tenants.

Meantime you can also create roles depends on the permission for a particular tenant. You can have different roles to cater your requirement. Please read [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Roles) document for more information on role management.